# reactjs how to handle value change on input array properly

Tags: arrays, reactjs, object, input, onchange

I have this form invoice registration created in reactJs.

[image: form invoice registration]

The Form should handle input array (marked with red outline). whenever onChange event occured on the input. all the input is receiving the same value. How to prooperly handle this ? I intended to use this input value to generated data like this below :

```
[
    {
        invoice_number:102947303364,
        invoice_registration_no : 1235
    },
    {
        invoice_number:102947109177,
        invoice_registration_no : 6578
    },
]
```

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: Its look like you are binding the referance and not value

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I do not know which is the primary key in DB, so I assumed invoice_number is the primary key.

```js
class CustomList extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.handleInputChange = this.handleInputChange.bind(this);
    this.renderList = this.renderList.bind(this);
    
    this.state = {
      data: [
          {
              invoice_number:102947303364,
              invoice_registration_no : 1235,
              some_value: '',
          }, {
              invoice_number:102947109177,
              invoice_registration_no : 6578,
              some_value: '',
          },
      ],
    }
  }
  
  handleInputChange(e){
    const {id, value} = e.target;
    let {data} = this.state;
    const targetIndex = data.findIndex(datum => {
      return datum.invoice_number == id;
    });

    if(targetIndex !== -1){
      data[targetIndex].some_value = value;
      this.setState({data});
    }
  }
  
  renderList() {
      const {data} = this.state;
      let content = data.map(datum => {
        return (
          <li id={datum.invoice_number}>
            <p>{datum.invoice_number}</p>
            <input type="text" id={datum.invoice_number} value={datum.some_value}
              onChange={this.handleInputChange}/>
          </li>
        )
      });
      return (
        <ul>
          {content}
        </ul>
      )
  }
  
  render() {
    const myList = this.renderList();
    return (
      <div>
        {myList}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
ReactDOM.render(
  <CustomList/>,
  document.getElementById('root')
)
```

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <div id="root"></div>
  </body>
</html>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
```

what you need to see is `handleInputChange` method binds to `CustomList` class and `renderList`.

I just set id property to invoice_number at each input and find changed input's index using `Array.prototype.findIndex`.

Comment: You could also declare `handleInputChange` like this: 

`handleInputChange = () => {...}`. Then you don't need to bind them in this ugly fashion :D

Comment: @Nocebo In fact, I usually use `::this.method` which is ES6 grammer to bind method to class. However Stack Overflow doesn't support ES6, so I habitually wrote like this. Thank you for telling me!

Comment: Oh I see. Yeah just trying to help ;) Have a nice day :)

Comment: @Nocebo Thank you again for your advice :)

Comment: @HyeonJunOh Thanks. Can you please tell how to highlight particular input box border and render small error text when certain required input are left empty when user clicks on Submit button ? I know how to do it for few input element on screen but how to do it for array of objects.